# Why echo "MYPASSWORD" | sudo -kS ls does not work on debian on Beaglebone

Tags: sudo, password

I am running a Beaglebone on Debian (4.14.108-ti-r113).
I need to run a root command from the debian user.
I tried many things that still result in error.

Some attempts:

```
$ echo "MYPASSWORD" | sudo -kS ls

[sudo] password for debian: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for debian: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt


$ sudo -S <<< MYPASSWORD ls
[sudo] password for debian: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for debian: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

$ echo -e "MYPASSWORD\n"|sudo -S 
[sudo] password for debian: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for debian: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

Note: MYPASSWORD does not contain $, only a-to-z characters

Any idea?

Comment: Correct, no $ in the password, only [a-z]

Comment: It's a `sudo` design choice. `sudo` tries to ensure password input comes from an interactive source. Read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: @waltinator It seems clear from the use of the `-S` option that Stéphane has already read the manual; that’s why I upvoted the question.  @Stéphane the only thing I could think of is that the password for the `debian` user is something other than `MYPASSWORD` – but that’s also in the realm of “too obvious to be the cause of the problem”. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I of course read the manual. Actually the default password for the debian distrib on the beaglebone is actually <tmppwd> without the brackets. I really scratches my head on this…